# Replacing zero values with small random number in data table using R in different columns

Tags: r

I have a data table with 411 rows and 6 variables and looks like this:

```
> head(datapp)
  TP220170823pos-42 TP220170823pos-43 TP220170823pos-44 TP220170823pos-48 TP220170823pos-49 TP220170823pos-50
1          22744.04          43727.39          25901.80          36771.81          23925.68          30524.43
2              0.00              0.00              0.00          37894.31          37103.62          33042.50
3          88752.27         139099.31          79979.00         130399.10          90345.01          90159.49
4          40225.14          72674.44          40121.52          61857.07          48736.48          46398.95
5              0.00              0.00              0.00          19587.50          10146.16          17582.49
6              0.00              0.00              0.00          54149.82          52733.90          54033.67
```

I want to change each zero value with a new random number for each variable. I first changed the name of each variable to make them similar and then used the following code:

```
names(datapp)[1:6] <- "intensity"

library(data.table)

setDT(as.data.frame(datapp))[intensity == 0, intensity := (runif(.N, 0, 1))]
```

However, when I run this code it only changes the 0's in the first column and not the other 5. Is there a way to also change the 0's with a random number in the other columns?

Comment: You can't have 6 columns all called "intensity". Only the first will be referenced when you try to reference them by name.

Comment: Thank for your comment, any idea on how to get this working for all columns?

Comment: `for(i in seq_along(datapp)) datapp[[i]][datapp[[i]] == 0] <- runif(nrow(datapp), 0, 1)`